# How to use friendly URL with KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: url, symfony, pagination

I installed KnpPaginatorBundle in my Symfony 2.1 project and also configure Paginator.

With pagination my URL looks like:

```
http://dev.localhost/app_dev.php/news/development?page=3
```

Is it possible to change URL to something like this (or similar - without ? and = character)?

```
http://dev.localhost/app_dev.php/news/development/page/3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution, to solve your problem, follow these steps:

1) Create a new route or change the old one, so in the routing.yml add this:

```
news_development_route:
    pattern: /news/development/{page}
    defaults: {_controller: AcmeMainBundle:Article:list, page: 1 }
```

2) In your class controller, change your method like this:

```
// Acme\MainBundle\Controller\ArticleController.php

public function listAction($page)/*add the $page param*/
{
    $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $dql   = "SELECT a FROM AcmeMainBundle:Article a";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', $page)/*change the number 1 by the $page parameter*/,
        10/*limit per page*/
    );
    $pagination->setUsedRoute('news_development_route'); /*define the pagination route*/

    // parameters to template
    return $this->render('AcmeMainBundle:Article:list.html.twig', array('pagination' => $pagination));
}
```

That's it

Comment: After two years. Thanks. I have tested and it works like a charm.

Comment: If you use variables in your route (e.g. `@Route("/list/{name}", name="_article_list")` , you can add them with `$pagination->addParam('name', 'Finance');`. I am still searching how to start with a clean URL (so unset all the current query string parameters).

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, you need change this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/list/", name="_user_list")
 * @Template()
 */
public function listAction()
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $dql = "SELECT a FROM HPPTarjetaBundle:User a";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        10/*limit per page*/
    );
    return compact('pagination');
}
```

... To this (see "page" parameter):

```
/**
 * @Route("/list/{page}", name="_user_list")
 * @Template()
 */
public function listAction($page)
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $dql = "SELECT a FROM HPPTarjetaBundle:User a";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query,
        $page/*page number*/,
        10/*limit per page*/
    );
    return compact('pagination');
}
```

Comment: I had an issue because the parameter doesn't has a default value however adding defaults={"page" = 1} solved it

Comment: If you rest in @DrMartin solution, you will have to specify the query string. I solved it this way: <a href="{{ path('my_rute') ~ "/" ~ myObject.Id}}">Details</a>. The "~" was ver useful. Consult the Twig official book: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/pdf/Twig.pdf‎, Chapter: Twig for Template Designers/Expressions. Good luck.